# I want to organise text file contents by descending score

Tags: python

I have a text file:

```
watermelon : 3
kiwi : 4
cucumber : 10
zucchini : 5
apple : 1
jalapeno : 8
pepper : 9
orange : 2
carrot : 6
banana : 11
okra : 7
```

I want my program to output:

```
banana : 11
cucumber : 10
pepper : 9
jalapeno : 8
okra : 7
carrot : 6
zucchini : 5
kiwi : 4
watermelon : 3
orange : 2
apple : 1
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Comment: *"Is there a way I can do this?"* - yes! *"if you could give me the... solution"* - not how this works, sorry. What have **you tried**, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @deW1 really? The second one is the first, sorted in descending order of the number after the colon.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to python. What I meant by 'Is there a way I can do this' was basically asking if any of you could come up with some code that would get my .txt file into the output I want in a program. I didnt mean any confustion, I just havent worded myself correctly. Sorry.

Comment: Stack Overflow **is not a code-writing service**. Yes, many of us *could* write what you need, but that's not what this site is about. **Do your own homework**, and read e.g. http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/110531.

Comment: I agree, I just needed some guidance for it. Thanks to everyone for all the feedback - I'll keep it in mind next time I have a problem in my code. FYI I absolutely love this website and only want to make it better. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:-

```
input_list = []
with open('input', 'r') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile.readlines():
        item, val = line.split(':')
        input_list.append((item.strip(), int(val.strip())))
    res_list = sorted(input_list, key=lambda input: input[1], reverse=True)

print res_list  #[('banana', 11), ('cucumber', 10), ('pepper', 9), ('jalapeno', 8), ('okra', 7), ('carrot', 6), ('zucchini', 5), ('kiwi', 4), ('watermelon', 3), ('orange', 2), ('apple', 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Instant solution!